# JSP pages of Spring boot web application is not loading when hosted in external tomcat as war package

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, war

The war file is deployed in external tomcat but the application URL is not loading the JSP page.
Same application is able to run and load jsp pages in ecllipse, also in comand promt using

```
 mvn spring-boot:run
```

Can anyone helps me in this scenario.

1.**pom.xml**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.accounts</groupId>
<artifactId>Accounts</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<name>Accounts</name>
<description>Accounts Project</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <start-class>com.accounts.AccountsApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Instruct spring boot not to use the inbuilt Tomcat server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2.Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccountsApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(AccountsApplication.class);
   }

 }
```

3.application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix =/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

4.Security config file

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/res/**","/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() 
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutsuccess").permitAll();

}
```

5. Controller code

   ```
   package com.accounts.Controller;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

   @Controller
   public class LoginController {

   @GetMapping("/login")
   public String login() {
      return "login";
   }

   @GetMapping("/logoutsuccess")
   public String logout() {
      return "login";
   }

   }
   ```
6. Click the below link to see the 404 Error shows in browser.
   [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llwkA.png)

Comment: What does Tomcat log when it deploys your application?

Comment: Do you have a controller?

Comment: The artifact `tomcat-jasper` might collide with the server's Jasper version. Try replacing it with `tomcat-embed-jasper` **without** the `<version>` tag (the version is managed by Spring Boot) and a scope of `provided`. I second Andy's comment: with any logs it is just guesswork.

Comment: Ans 1. Tomcat not showing any logs while accessing the URL.

Comment: Ans 2. As spring security is defined ,to authorize requests when application loads it will redirect to login :-  /login - then it should show the login page - which is not showing. Other requests which already have permission to load without authorization is also not loading....controller code is added above now

Comment: Ans 3. Maven tomcat-embed-jasper also tried and its not worked